# Why is this encryption failing?

Tags: java, c#, encryption

I found the following code on an encryption website ... it works as a Java client and a C# server. This code works great except there is one problem I cannot figure out. If I send small messages everything is fine ... the problem starts when I send more than 47 char to the server at this point it fails with the following error:

> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Can someone look this over or possibly test it for themselves and find a solution … thanks.

Java Code:

```
public class Crypto {

private final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
private final String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private final String aesEncryptionAlgorithm = "AES";

public  byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpecy = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpecy, ivParameterSpec);
    cipherText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    return cipherText;
}

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] key, byte [] initialVector) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, aesEncryptionAlgorithm);
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initialVector);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    plainText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
    return plainText;
}

private byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    byte[] keyBytes= new byte[16];
    byte[] parameterKeyBytes= key.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    System.arraycopy(parameterKeyBytes, 0, keyBytes, 0, Math.min(parameterKeyBytes.length, keyBytes.length));
    return keyBytes;
}

/// <summary>
/// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
/// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException{
    byte[] plainTextbytes = plainText.getBytes(characterEncoding);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt(plainTextbytes,keyBytes, keyBytes), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

/// <summary>
/// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
/// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
public String decrypt(String encryptedText, String key) throws KeyException, GeneralSecurityException, GeneralSecurityException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, IOException{
    byte[] cipheredBytes = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] keyBytes = getKeyBytes(key);
    return new String(decrypt(cipheredBytes, keyBytes, keyBytes), characterEncoding);
}
```

C# Code:

```
class Crypto
{
    public static string currentPassword;

    public RijndaelManaged GetRijndaelManaged(String secretKey)
    {
        var keyBytes = new byte[16];
        var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
        Array.Copy(secretKeyBytes, keyBytes, Math.Min(keyBytes.Length, secretKeyBytes.Length));
        return new RijndaelManaged
        {
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            KeySize = 128,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Key = keyBytes,
            IV = keyBytes
        };
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged)
    {
        return rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
    /// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
    /// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
    public String Encrypt(String plainText, String key)
    {
        var plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(plainBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts a base64 encoded string using the given key (AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encryptedText">Base64 Encoded String</param>
    /// <param name="key">Secret Key</param>
    /// <returns>Decrypted String</returns>
    public String Decrypt(String encryptedText, String key)
    {
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(encryptedBytes, GetRijndaelManaged(key)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check what you are sending, byte by byte.  There may be some newline characters inserted in the Base64 string, which would give the result you see.  You may need to explicitly chop your Base64 into lines, and reassemble it at the receiving end.

Comment: Actually i have done that ... funny thing is like I said its all fine if I send small chunks of data. anything over 47 char fails ... very strange.

Comment: chopping off the newline is what I am doing, but if I send anything over 47 char it fails and then says Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.

Comment: I had one similar problem with a Java Client and C# Backend. I exchanged RSA-Key generated in Java and I had to chop of the first Byte  to make them work in c#. Try to check to Byte-Arrays.

Comment: I figured out what was going on, for some reason after a certain amount of char java ads a "\n" in the middle of the encrypted text  ... so when I was chopping in c# i was inadvertently removing half of the message... what I need to do was chop at "\n\n" which is the actual end of the message and not just "\n" which like I said removed a portion of the message. But can't figure out why java is adding in this newline char.

Comment: It may be adding `\r\n` which Windows based systems use.

Comment: Originally base 64 was used for SMIME, where a number of base 64 character needs to be followed by a `\r\n` code. Maybe that's the issue? Different base 64 encoders / decoders may have different defaults.